# Why he return 11 all the time ??? (btw. now is 16 h my local time)

Tags: android, time, calendar

```
private void hour()
{
    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Here coding and formatting standards help. In Java, it is customary to have constants written in all uppercase with words separated with underscores.

Comment: Thanks David and JRL,  I  will try to observed the  rules :)

Answer (score 5):

Because you just parsed the value of HOUR_OF_DAY which is 11. Forever and ever.

You should create an instance of GregorianCalendar, give it the current date, and use `get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

Code sample:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Comment: I've made that type of mistake before.  Makes for a good slap on the forehead when you find the bug :)

Comment: Thanks a  lot WarrenFaith :))

Comment: thats why my wrist is always tied to the table :)